# Missing rates and multiple imputation

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

Is there a limit which is the least acceptable when using multiple imputation (MI)?

For example can I use MI if the missing values in a variable are the 20% of the cases while and other variables have missing values but not to such a high level?

Comment: I wouldn't consider 20% very high, so I'm sure the answer to your second question is yes, although I don't have a rigorous justification. My gut feeling is that the only limit is that which prevents the algorithm from working at all. I vaguely remember seeing a table in Rubin's book showing results for very high rates of missingness. Whether it's worthwhile (as opposed to valid) doing MI with very high rates of missingness is another question.

Comment: A lot will depend on how much you can assume your missings are missing completely at random. If there is a high percentage of missings and they're not missing at random, you may get biased estimates for the imputation. Because it has to be done on cases present in the data (by definition), where there is a systematic bias in the missing cases the present cases may not be very informative from an accuracy perspective.

Comment: @mark999 - Thanks for the answer. When the rate of missingness for one variable can be considered as high? Regarding your last question do you have any answer?

Comment: @Michelle - Thank you. Fortunately the hypothesis MAR is quite plausible (and even the MCAR could be considered plausible)

Comment: @Nick: I don't know what should be considered a very high rate, and I don't think it's necessary to put a specific number on it. I don't have an answer to the last question.

Comment: @Michelle I think you've mixed MCAR, MAR and NMAR here, making the first two sentences of your comment false.  Imputation is potentially bias-removing for MAR (and MCAR) data.  Under MAR, biased estimates after imputation come from having an insufficiently rich imputation model and/or from the existence of NMAR elements. For purely NMAR elements, imputation need not help and does risk bias, obviously.

Comment: @ConjugatePrior my comment said "and they're not missing at random".

Comment: @Michelle, Ah ok, I assumed you were talking about MCARs of the first sentence, which are irrelevant to imputation bias.  Then I think the whole comment then makes good sense if 'completely' is removed in the first sentence.  Curse the useless terminology!

Comment: @ConjugatePrior yes, I wish I could delete just that one word.

Comment: @Michelle :-) I had a similar problem with 'non' on this very page, which Peter Flom just caught.  I don't normally expect karma to operate on such a short scale...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments, you're confident that your in a MAR or MCAR situation.  Then multiple imputation is at least reasonable.  So how much missingness is tractable?  Think of it this way:

Basically, multiple imputation makes all your model parameter estimates less certain as a function of the accuracy with which the missing data can be predicted with your imputation model, which will depend, among other things, on the amount of missing that needs imputing, and the number of imputations you use.

How much is 'too much' missingness therefore depends on how much added variance/uncertainty you are willing to put up with.  A useful quantity for you might be the relative efficiency ($RE$) of an MI analysis.  This depends on the 'fraction of missing information' (not the simple rate of missingness), usually called $\lambda$, and the number of imputations, usually called $m$, as $RE \approx 1/(1+\lambda/m)$.

Rather than generate the definitions of missing information etc. here, you might simply read the [MI FAQ](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/STA6167/Missing%20Data/MI_FAQ.pdf) which puts things very clearly.  From there you'll know whether you want to tackle the original sources: Rubin etc.

Practically speaking you should probably just try an imputation analysis and see how it works out.

Comment: the FAQ link is broken. Any chance you might have a current one? (it looks useful)

Comment: Added.  Not sure how official it is though.

Answer (score 1):

You might find

> Rubin, Donald B. and Nathaniel Schenker. 1986. “Multiple Imputation
>   for Interval Estimation from Simple Random Samples with Ignorable
>   Nonresponse.” Journal of the American Statistical Association
>   81(394):366–374.

helpful.

Comment: Could you please summarize in few words Rubin's recommendations so that this reply remains self-contained?

Comment: I will have to get that.  I have also heard Joe Shaffer of Penn State say (much more recently) that MI is good unless the data are "REALLY nonignorable"

Comment: @Peter Flom: Shaffer's statement is interesting - do you know any details?

Comment: @mark999 It was made at a talk he gave, about 10 years ago, so I don't really recall details. I haven't searched for his recent papers on the topic, but it might be there.

Comment: @Peter Flom: Thanks (I mistakenly interpreted your "much more recently" as "recently").

Comment: @Peter Flom: presumably 'really ignorable' means data that is NMAR/NI and cannot be made reasonably MAR however much you try adding possibly informative covariates.

Comment: @ConjugatePrior "really nonignorable" not really ignorable. And he meant data sets where the missingness created a lot of bias.

Comment: @Peter Flom. Typo on my part I'm afraid.  Rest of my comment makes sense if you put the missing 'non' in front!